# Cambiar de tamaño el icono launcher

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando ejecuto mi aplicacion el icono launcher sale muy pequeño a comparacion de todos los que tengo ahi quiero saber el porque y la solución, ya probé con darle una imagen de 512x512 y una mucha mas grande pero sigue igual mi icono es mas pequeño que los demas.

Comment: Como añades la imagen para mostrarla como icono? Según como la añadas, Android Studio la redimensiona

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos, te sugiero leer [ask], es importante para que tus preguntas sea mejor recibida y tengan buenas respuestas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera medalla.

Comment: Si no cambia la imagen siendo que definiste una imagen más grande como icono, entonces el problema seguramente es que estas definiendo otra imagen como icono, probablemente en otro folder esto revisalo en tu AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de la dencidad de la pantalla del dispositivo el sistema mostrara el icono que este indicado para esa densidad. Tienes que crear 6 iconos con distintos tamaños como se indica a continuacion:

```
48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store)
```

Puedes generarlos en Android Estudio utilizando el [Image Assets](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html).

Seleciona el proyecto y luego ve a la opcion **File->New->Image Asset**. Selecciona el radio **Image** y busca la imagen que quieres agregar como laucher:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego le asignas un nombre y presiones **next/continuar** y android studio generar los iconos y los pondra en las carpetas correspondiente segun las dencidades disponibles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien puedes crear los iconos para los Actions Bars, Tabs y Notificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

> Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación el icono launcher sale muy pequeño a
>   comparación de todos los que tengo ahí quiero saber el porque y la
>   solución, ya probé con darle una imagen de 512x512 y una mucha mas
>   grande pero sigue igual mi icono es mas pequeño que los demás.

**Tienes que revisar dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` que icono estas cargando como [icon launcher](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html) de la aplicación**, esto es definido dentro de la propiedad `android:icon` dentro de `application`.

En este caso el icono launcher debe estar dentro del folder `/mipmap` que es como actualmente se realiza:

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

En proyectos anteriores se definia dentro del folder `/drawable` :

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Simplemente asegura que tienes definido el folder e icono correcto dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

---

**La medidas definida para [Launcher icons](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html) en un dispositivo móvil deben tener 48x48 dp**, esto significa que el baseline es:

```
48 × 48 pixeles para mdpi (densidad media)
72 × 72 pixeles para hdpi (densidad alta)
96 × 96 pixeles para xhdpi (densidad extra-alta) 
144 × 144 pixeles para xxhdpi (densidad extra-extra-alta) 
192 × 192 pixeles para xxxhdpi (densidad extra-extra-extra-alta) 
512 × 512 pixeles para imagen Google Play store.
```

Considera revisar la [documentación](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html) para referencia con las medidas.

Answer (score 0):

Es a causa de que estas confundiendo el nombre del icono

```
Name: ic_launcher
```

al cambiar la imagen y asignar el nombre, estás cambiando el de

```
Layer Name: ic_launcher_foreground
```

y desde el manifiest estas llamando al archivo del Layer Name: ic_launcher_foreground

seguramente borraste de Layer Name: ic_launcher_foreground la palabra: foreground y la sustituiste por la de tu imagen esto es un error.

desde el manifest estas llamando al archivo Layer Name: ic_launcher_(nombre de tu imagen)
por eso se ve pequeña.
lo correccto es llamar desde el manifets a Name ic_lancher  o el nombre que le pongas pero al apartado de Name ic_lancher.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]